# Calculate percentage change between two div numbers

Tags: javascript, html

I have two divs `<div id="originalValue">100</div>` and `<div id="currentValue">50</div>` how can i calculate the percentage change between them?

Comment: you want to know how to do the percentage? or how [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) these elements in js? or what?

Comment: `currentPercent = current / (original / 100)`, thus, 50 of 100 is 50% (or -50%), 20 of 100 is 20% (or -80%), 10 of 200 is 5% (or -95%) and so on...

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var curr=document.getElementById('currentValue').innerHTML;
var origin=document.getElementById('originalValue').innerHTML;
var percent=(+curr/+origin)*100
console.log(percent);
```

Answer (score 1):

To go with your style, here's one way of doing it:

```
<div id="originalValue">100</div>
<div id="currentValue">50</div>

<script>
  var percentage = document.createElement('div');
  percentage.innerHTML = 100 * (document.getElementById('currentValue').innerHTML / document.getElementById('originalValue').innerHTML);
  document.body.appendChild(percentage);
</script>
```